# Calculate total price based on checkboxes

Tags: python, jquery, django

I want when someone click on checkbox this price adding in to  total price. Or button will be better?

I use Django models and form for visual on HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const ID_CHECK_1 = 'id_checkbox_1';
  const ID_CHECK_2 = 'id_checkbox_2';
  const ID_CHECK_3 = 'id_checkbox_3';

  const ID_PRICE_1 = 'id_price_1';
  const ID_PRICE_2 = 'id_price_2';
  const ID_PRICE_3 = 'id_price_3';

  const ID_TOTAL_PRICE = 'id_total_price';

  var $check1 = $('#' + ID_CHECK_1);
  var $check2 = $('#' + ID_CHECK_2);
  var $check3 = $('#' + ID_CHECK_3);

  var $price1 = $('#' + ID_PRICE_1);
  var $price2 = $('#' + ID_PRICE_2);
  var $price3 = $('#' + ID_PRICE_3);

  var $total = $('#' + ID_TOTAL_PRICE);
  var totalPrice = $total.val();

  $($check1).click(function() {
    if ($check1.is(":checked")) {
      totalPrice += parseFloat($price1.val());
    }

    if ($check2.is(":checked")) {
      totalPrice += Number($price2.val());
    }
    
    if ($check3.is(":checked")) {
      totalPrice += Number($price3.val());
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Firstly, do you have a specific issue with the code? Secondly, can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can create a working example of the problem. (Note, we need the HTML code here, not django, or any other server side code which *creates* the HTML)

Comment: what is your issue here ? side note - do not mutilply variable names like this, `$("#id_price3").val()` is more comprehensible than with all your variables

Comment: Dear Rory,          
No i havent problem with code. Me need make this jquery for counting total price.
https://github.com/KoonAgni/hmls/commit/aa815796e05bdc8365b314dc360c66df2aa2d14c

Comment: Dear Lous-Justin,
Not issue, just someone told"Don't declare variables inside of if/for statements. If you absolutely have to, use let, that's what let is for" that why a write like this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare your variables simpler. Not really necessary to save the ID as a constant when you only need the element anyways.

```
    var check1 = $('#id_checkbox_1');
    var check2 = $('#id_checkbox_2');
    var check3 = $('#id_checkbox_3');

    var price1 = $('#id_price_1');
    var price2 = $('#id_price_2');
    var price3 = $('#id_price_3');

    var total = $('#id_total_price');

    var totalPrice = total.val();
```

is there a reason you prepend $ to your variable names? I am not familiar with django, but in Javascript / JQuery $ refers to jQuery and should not be used in variable names.

You also only add an event listener on one element, check1.
Assuming you want a checked element to add to the current price and removing itself as soon as unchecked:

```
$('input:checkbox).off('click').on('click', function() {
    // selects all <div> elements with checkbox attribute and adds click listener
    // off() prevents event listeners stacking
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // $(this) refers to the element the event occured on
        totalVal += currentprice;
    } else {
        totalVal -= currentprice;
    }
});
```

Don't forget your semicolons!

Now assuming you have more than three priced elements you want to include, it would be useful to connect element and price. currently you grab your elements and prices via id. How does your HTML structure look?

For calculating a price, you could store the number in a data attribute.

```
// set price
check1.data('price', 235.5);

// read price 
var price1 = check1.data('price');
```

Or you create objects.
The exact code you need strongly depends on your HTML structure and what you exactly want to do.